# Compile Visual Studio project by minifying css and js

Tags: javascript, css, vb.net, minify

I have the following doubt:
I have a project in Vb.net and I would like the compilation of the project to be minified and unified css files (App_Themes) on one side and js linked (in a common folder).

```
App_Themes/FrontEnd/general.css
App_Themes/FrontEnd/main.css
App_Themes/FrontEnd/css.css

Js/jquery.js
Js/main.js
```

Would this be possible in any way?
Thank you :)

Comment: Are you using visual studio? If so maybe this link can help you along 
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.BundlerMinifier

Comment: This version not found un VS 2013. :(

Comment: Ah alright then maybe this topic can help you out then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27549427/in-visual-studio-2013-how-do-i-minify-javascript-and-css-in-the-post-build-step

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [gulp](http://gulpjs.com) for that. There are many plugins on npm to help you such as [gulp-uglify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify) for CSS and Javascript minification.

Hope I helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/). Gulp is a **task/build** runner for development. It allows you to do a lot of stuff within your development workflow.  See also [this](https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/using-gulp-js-and-the-task-runner-explorer-in-asp-net-5/).

Answer (score 0):

Hello again The problem I have is that the css are linked through App_Themes. I think there is nothing that allows to do the minification and unification of styles when compiling by topic right?

Thank you for your help.